# Twig incorrect truncated html

Tags: html, twig, truncate

I save news text in DB as HTML:

```
<p>Hello, i'm a text!</p><p> More text</p>
```

When i render text like this

```
{{ post.body | raw }}
```

everything goes well, but i need to truncate text to 20-30 symbols for preview on main page.
So, i tried

```
{{ p.body[:20] ~ '..' }}
```

and then text looks like

```
<p>Hello, i'm..
```

How can a hide than html tags? "|raw" filter also does not working while truncation.
Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conveniently, Twig has a built in function for stripping out HTML tags.

The following would output "Hello, i'm a text ..."

```
{% set some_html = "<p>Hello, i'm a text!</p><p> More text</p>" %}
{{ some_html[:20]|striptags ~ ' ...' }}
```

Comment: What would be even more convenient is a truncate that preserves the HTML, truncates based on visible words, but closes the current set of tags. [This extension](https://gist.github.com/leon/2857883) may do that (I have not tested).